# Assinatura SHA256 padrão do eSocial vs. Framework .Net 4.6

Tags: c#, api, rsa, sha-256

Bom dia pessoal,

Eu possuo uma aplicação desenvolvida em C#, instalada em diversos clientes.

Desenvolvi o trecho de código abaixo para a assinatura em SHA256 e funciona perfeitamente nos FRAMEWORKS mais modernos do .NET:

```
class Assinatura
{
    public string AssinarSHA256(Int32 lnEvento,
        string arqXMLAssinar,
        string tagAssinatura,
        string tagAtributoId,
        X509Certificate2 x509Cert,
        string lxURI)
    {
        try
        {
            string xmlString;
            xmlString = arqXMLAssinar;

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            // Format the document to ignore white spaces.
            doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;

            doc.LoadXml(xmlString);

            XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = null;

            // Load the passed XML file using it’s name.

            if (doc.GetElementsByTagName(tagAssinatura).Count == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("A tag de assinatura " + tagAssinatura.Trim() + " não existe no XML. (Código do Erro: 5)");
            }
            else if (doc.GetElementsByTagName(tagAtributoId).Count == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("A tag de assinatura " + tagAtributoId.Trim() + " não existe no XML. (Código do Erro: 4)");
            }
            // Existe mais de uma tag a ser assinada
            else
            {
                XmlNodeList lists = doc.GetElementsByTagName(tagAssinatura);

                if (lists.Count != 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Existe mais de uma TAG definida como tag da assinatura");
                    throw new Exception("Existe mais de uma tag de assinatura " + tagAtributoId.Trim() + " não existe no XML. (Código do Erro: 6)");
                }

                #region assinatura sha256 funcionando
                foreach (XmlNode nodes in lists)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode childNodes in nodes.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        if (!childNodes.Name.Equals(tagAtributoId))
                            continue;

                        // Create a reference to be signed
                        Reference reference = new Reference();

                        reference.Uri = lxURI;

                        // Create a SignedXml object.
                        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);

                        signedXml.SigningKey = x509Cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();

                        signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";

                        // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
                        XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();

                        reference.AddTransform(env);

                        XmlDsigC14NTransform c14 = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();

                        reference.AddTransform(c14);

                        reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";


                        // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
                        signedXml.AddReference(reference);

                        // Create a new KeyInfo object
                        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();

                        // Load the certificate into a KeyInfoX509Data object
                        // and add it to the KeyInfo object.
                        keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(x509Cert));

                        // Add the KeyInfo object to the SignedXml object.
                        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

                        signedXml.ComputeSignature();

                        // Get the XML representation of the signature and save
                        // it to an XmlElement object.
                        xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

                        // Gravar o elemento no documento XML
                        nodes.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

                    }
                }

                #endregion



                // Atualizar a string do XML já assinada
                return doc.OuterXml;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException ex)
        {

            throw new Exception("Mensagem:" + ex.Message + "\n" +
                "Trace:" + ex.StackTrace + "\n" +
                "Dados" + ex.Data + "\n" +
                ex.ToString());// #12342 concatenar com a mensagem original
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Meu problema é que alguns clientes possuem o SISTEMA OPERACIONAL Windows XP, que limita a utilização somente a Frameworks do .NET anteriores ou iguais ao 4.6 e não consegui encontrar nada similar para substituir a função :

```
signedXml.SigningKey = x509Cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
```

Que só se faz presente nas versões mais atuais do framework .net

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?!

Comment: Pode fazer o upgrade do sistema operacional e resolver fácil :) Usar XP hoje é suicídio, até entendo haver legado, mas pelo menos não deveria por nada novo nele. Eu diria para pegar os fontes da classe e trazer pra sua aplicação, mas tenho quase certeza que este método especificamente depende diretamente do sistema operacional e não vai resolver. Tente ver no Mono, mas acho que a solução será complicada.

Comment: Compreendo, mas esses clientes são prefeituras o que torna tudo mais difícil. Neste momento a atualização dos sistemas é algo impensável por eles.

Comment: Prefeituras deveriam ser as primeiras a usar produtos conformes. Se quem tem que zelar pelo bom funcionamento da sociedade não o faz com si própria, estamos fú. Lamento você estar envolvido em algo tão malfadado.

Comment: @HeitorMagaldi agora não dá mais pra fugir. Desde semana passada o próprio TI público 'obsoleceu' esquemas antigos de criptografia. Se realmente for precisar disso, vai ter que escrever sua própria camada de compatibilidade. (a SEFAZ mesmo adotou na NFe 4 padrões novos de criptografia, que não tem suporte ao XP. detalhe: foi adiada por causa dessa resistência - mas essa tendência não se limita a sistemas de NFe só)